# Flutter loading text animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-text, flutter-container

How to achieve [this effect](https://codepen.io/codypearce/pen/LYVoNGy) with Flutter? Preferably with something like `animatedContainer`, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Look at this package: **animated_text_kit**

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit

See the Wavy pattern...

[image]

```
return DefaultTextStyle(
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.0,
  ),
  child: AnimatedTextKit(
    animatedTexts: [
      WavyAnimatedText('Hello World'),
      WavyAnimatedText('Look at the waves'),
    ],
    isRepeatingAnimation: true,
    onTap: () {
      print("Tap Event");
    },
  ),
);
```

**Solution 2:**

There are several more general packages that provide out of the box and ready to use Loading animations... (but not necessarily the exact same animation from your link)

**Links:**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading

[Flutter loading text animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74606342/flutter-loading-text-animation)

[Flutter loading text animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74606342/flutter-loading-text-animation)